# Why is the number formatting abnormal?

Tags: php, number-formatting

So i wanted to display a counter with each char wrapped in a tag and also add a thousands seprator.

The number must be atleast 3 char long.

**Case 1:**

I took a number `12`

*the code:*

```
$number = 12 //number 12
$number = number_format($number, 0, '', ','); //add a thousand seprator
$number = str_pad($number,3,0,STR_PAD_LEFT); //pad if length less than 3
$counter = "";
foreach (str_split($number) as $key => $digit) {
    $counter .= '<b>' . $digit . '</b>';
}
```

Output: `012` (ignoring the `<b>` tag)

**Case 2:**

I took a number `1234`

*the code:*

```
$number = 1234 //number 1234
$number = number_format($number, 0, '', ','); //add a thousand seprator
$number = str_pad($number,3,0,STR_PAD_LEFT); //pad if length less than 3
$counter = "";
foreach (str_split($number) as $key => $digit) {
    $counter .= '<b>' . $digit . '</b>';
}
```

Output: `1,234` (ignoring the `<b>` tag)

**Case 3:**

I took a number `0012`

*the code:*

```
$number = 0012 //number 0012
$number = number_format($number, 0, '', ','); //add a thousand seprator
$number = str_pad($number,3,0,STR_PAD_LEFT); //pad if length less than 3
$counter = "";
foreach (str_split($number) as $key => $digit) {
    $counter .= '<b>' . $digit . '</b>';
}
```

Output: `010` (ignoring the `<b>` tag)

---

So what went wrong in **case 3**?

**Update:**

How to avoid this?

Comment: `0012` is _not_ a decimal. It is interpreted s an octal notation as documented.

Comment: @arkascha Well, it *is* an integer. An integer in octal notation... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is, because **octal**:

```
$number = 0012;
```

The `0` prefix causes PHP to transform `12` using octal to decimal conversion; and 12 octal == 10 decimal.

To avoid this you could use string values instead:

```
$number = '0012';
```

See also: [Integer notation](http://sg3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#example-82)

Comment: How can I avoid this? So define it as an `(int)` will be appropriate

Comment: @blo Updated answer. An (int) typecast will not help because it was already an integer.

Comment: @blo Integer numbers do not include formatting information. "0012" (ignoring octal notation) is the same **value** as 12 is the same value as 0000012. The integer itself is just the *value* "12", leading zeros are irrelevant to it. You only add leading zeros when formatting numbers for output.

Comment: I tried `'0012'` it outputs `012` whereas expected was `0,012`. I'm guessing this format is invalid, am I correct?

Comment: @blo That's because `'0012'` expressed as a number is smaller than a thousand and therefore doesn't need a thousand separator. If that's your requirement, you shouldn't use `number_format()`.

Comment: @Jack I understood what your are saying, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Jack thanks again, but the regexp didn't help for numbers greater than 4 chars, anyway I get my number without padded 0, I was just curious about this outcome.